# Print .net coordinates units

Tags: .net, printing, draw

please help me. I want to print some reports from .NET app.
I read how to use PrintDocument class and Graphics object to draw my report.
But i don`t know which units are used in methods, for example:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPrintPage(ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPrintPage(e)

    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter
    Dim p As New Pen(Brushes.Red, 5)
    g.DrawRectangle(p, 5, 5, g.VisibleClipBounds.Width - 10, g.VisibleClipBounds.Height - 10)

End Sub
```

in method:

```
Public Sub DrawRectangle(ByVal pen As System.Drawing.Pen, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single, ByVal width As Single, ByVal height As Single)
```

parameters x,y,width,height are in pixels,millimeters,inches or what?

I try to find answer on google but founded nothing.
I am completely confused.

Thanks

Comment: i changed code, but g.VisibleClipBounds.Width returnts 799.333, and it`s too much pro A4 page if it`s in millimeters

Comment: Cicik, if you make changes to the code please mark them as such. Did the GraphicsUnit.Millimeter help?

Comment: ok in future i will mark changes, and no millimeter didn`t help.
rectangle is always out of apge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `PageUnit` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.pageunit.aspx

which could be any one (except `World`) of these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphicsunit.aspx